# DbContext cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query when getting table data asynchronously

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the above error, when I run this method in my view model for my WPF app:

```
public async Task LoadTypesAsync()
        {
            EquipmentTypes = await _equipmentRepository.GetEquipmentTypes();
        }
```

This calls a method in my repository that returns a list of Equipment Types as shown here:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EquipmentType>> GetEquipmentTypes()
        {
            return await _context.EquipmentTypes.Select(t => new EquipmentType()
            {
                EquipmentTypeID = t.EquipmentTypeID,
                EquipmentTypeDescription = t.EquipmentTypeDescription,
                EquipmentTypeName = t.EquipmentTypeName

            }).ToListAsync();
        }
```

When my main view model loads, I call the LoadTypesAsync method to save the data in my EquipmentTypes property, which is of type IEnumerable.

I really don't understand this error. What is preventing me from grabbing the data and inserting it into my list? My repository maintains a constant connection to the DB and can do other functions like inserting data just fine.

The error is shown when I call the LoadAsync method here:

```
public async Task LoadAsync() //method must be async when loading in async data and return a task
        {
            await EquipmentListViewModel.LoadAsync(); //load up the list to the left
            await EquipmentCreateViewModel.LoadTypesAsync();
        }
```

I'm unsure if I can have several awaits in an async method.

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace of exception?

Comment: Might need to show where and how _context is initialised within your class.  Sounds like that's where the problem is.

Comment: What is the `Select` doing in your `GetEquipmentTypes`? It rather looks like for every `EquipmentType` it gets it creates a new `EquipmentType` from it, and gives you that instead. If so, why?